# How can I HGET from many hashes in one request in StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have like 1000 hashes, and some of them has the same key, i.e.

```
Hash1 = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 5, 4: 7...}
Hash2 = {1: 4, 3: 5, 9: 7...}
Hash3 = {5: 4, 8: 5, 9: 7...}
...
```

I want to get all key `1` values in all hashes. I can do this:

```
List<value> values = new();
foreach (string hashKey in hashKeys)
{
  values.Add(await _client.HashGetAsync(hashKey, "1"));
}

return values;
```

But this do network to Redis `hashKeys.Count()` times. Can I do this in only one network request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not *directly via an inbuilt API* - there is no single redis API that achieves this. However, you *could* use Lua (`ScriptEvaluate`), passing in multiple keys, looping inside the Lua code, and building a result array by calling `hget` repeatedly.